# Conversion of int to UINT32

Tags: visual-c++, directx-11

OK, here it goes. I am creating wrapper for directx and struck with types. I know I'm dreadful, but please point me in right direction.

```
Platform::Array<short>^ Font::GetGlyphIndices(const Platform::Array<int>^ codePoints)
{
font->GetGlyphIndices(const UINT32 *codePoints, UINT32 count, UINT16 *indices);

Platform::Array<short>^ in; //should return indices

return in;
}
```

How can I convert types?
VS throw error as `"signature of public member contains native type 'int []'"`. So, updated code.

Comment: type casting? `(newtype)oldtype`. Example: `int i; char ch = '\n'; i = (int) ch;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using managed C++ along with native C++. So the best bet is to allocate native pointers (array) of UINT32, get the data from native function and run a loop to get values into managed array (`in`). And then return. You cannot, and should not mix managed and unmanaged memory. So, it is very much in favour to write *conversion* for the array!

Comment: I already started with loop. But thought there must be some direct way. Seems no. Thanks!

Comment: Marshal::Copy is there, for this purpose. But running a loop is much better approach. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cew0s1h.aspx